# Use of variable and space in f string in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to replace a value in a file with some space and a value from a variable but I am unable to get the right replace with f string in it

reg.yaml

```
row_filters:
  NONE:
    filter_sql_expr: True
rule_dimensions:
  - consistency
  - correctness
  - duplication
  - completeness
  - conformance
  - integrity
  - accuracy
```

**Code:**

```
f = open("C:\\Users\\dd00849401\\Documents\\yamls\\reg.yaml", 'r')
filter_exp = 'True'
newf = f.read().replace(f'filter_sql_expr: {filter_exp}', f"""filter_sql_expr:|- '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' ''{filter_exp}""")
f.close()
with open('C:\\Users\\dd00849401\\Documents\\yamls\\updated_test.yaml', 'w') as ff:
    ff.write(newf)
    ff.close()
```

**output:**

```
row_filters:
  NONE:
    filter_sql_expr: True
```

**Expected:**

```
row_filters:
  NONE:
    filter_sql_expr:|- 
          True
```

How can modify the f string in the replace function so that it can read both the spaces and variable.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the data in your `reg.yaml` file or a sample, so that we can better understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: You don't *do* anything with `newf`.

Comment: @user56700 sure I have modified the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace

```
newf = f.read().replace(f'filter_sql_expr: {filter_exp}', f"""filter_sql_expr:|- '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' ''{filter_exp}""")
```

with

```
newf = f.read().replace(f'filter_sql_expr: {filter_exp}',
    f"filter_sql_expr:|-\n          {filter_exp}")
```

Works well:

```
$ cat test 
row_filters:
  NONE:
    filter_sql_expr: True
rule_dimensions:
  - consistency
  - correctness
  - duplication
  - completeness
  - conformance
  - integrity
  - accuracy
$ nano test.py  # original version
$ python test.py 
$ cat out 
row_filters:
  NONE:
    filter_sql_expr:|- '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' ''True
rule_dimensions:
  - consistency
  - correctness
  - duplication
  - completeness
  - conformance
  - integrity
  - accuracy
$ nano test.py  # fixed version
$ python test.py 
$ cat out 
row_filters:
  NONE:
    filter_sql_expr:|-
          True
rule_dimensions:
  - consistency
  - correctness
  - duplication
  - completeness
  - conformance
  - integrity
  - accuracy
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer the problem is its not working with boolean update filter_exp = 'True'

Comment: @RoxaneFelton Are you trying to match a bool with a string, a string with a bool, a bool with a bool or a string with a string?

Comment: @Haukland filter_exp ='True' is a String value which I want to replace with boolean True in the reg.yaml. But the replace function doesnt work with boolean so how can i updated the same

Comment: @RoxaneFelton I have checked, see edited answer and I would say it works as you described what is desired...